# Cone $CX$ is always contractible , homeomorphisms with unit ball

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The following question was asked in my assignment of Topology course and I am struck on it.

> Question: Given a topological space $X$, the cone $CX$ is defined as the quotient of the cylinder $X \times [0, 1]$ in which all the points of $X ×$ {1} are identified:

1. Show that for all topological spaces  $X, CX$ is contractible.
2. Show that $C S^{n-1} $ is homeomorphic to $D^n$ and that $C D^n$ is homeomorphic to $ D^{n+1}$.

Attempt:  I have managed to prove 1 using $H' : (X \times I) \times I \longrightarrow X \times I \ , \qquad H'((x,t),s) = (x, t(1-s))$  composed with identification map $\pi : X\times I \longrightarrow CX \ , \qquad \pi (x,t) = [x,t] $.

But I am not able to prove (2).

Can you please shed light on how should (2) be done?

Comment: Hint: every point $p$ in the unit ball can be identified with the pair $(|p|,p/|p|)$ (magnitude and unit vector indicating direction.)

Comment: For the first case, you can think of projecting $CS^{-1}$ onto $D^n$ as you would do for $n=2$, and for $CD^n$, you can think of deforming it into a 'cylinder' (think of the case $n=1$, where $CD^{1}$ is a triangle, and inscribe it in a square, then project from the center of the square, or for $n=2$ a pyramid expanded to a cylinder) (the explicit formula for this would probably be awful, but feasible), which in turn is homeomorphic to $D^{n+1}$ for you can again expand it to the 'cylinder' (with much suffering, I fear). For explicit homeomorphisms I can't think of anything more direct.

Comment: All the hints you are getting are hints on how to prove the statement in your exercise, but there is a better route: make the statement of the excercise obvious to you. How? Compute some cones! Start with the cone over a point, then over a space with two points, then over finitely many points, then over a segment, then over a circle, then over a disc, then over a sphere...

Comment: The reason for which you are having problems proving that the cone over a sphere is a ball is that you do not know that the cone over a sphere is a ball: it is almost impossible to prove things that one does not know to be true (or at least suspects them to be). In all likelihood, you do not know what the cone over *anything* is, so solve that problem first.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you very much for advice!

Answer (score 2):

For any subspace $X\subset\mathbb R^n$, we have $X\times I\subset\mathbb R^{n+1}$ and we can embed the cone using $CX\hookrightarrow\mathbb R^{n+1},[(x,t)]\mapsto((1-t)x,t)$.

Imagine this for $X=S^1$: You get the surface of an ordinary cone without the bottom circle, so you can just flatten it down onto this bottom circle and get $CX\cong D^2$.

In arbitary dimensions, this is the postcomposition of the upper map with the map $\mathbb R^{n+1}\twoheadrightarrow\mathbb R^n$, that forgets the last coordinate, so we get a map $f\colon CS^{n-1}\rightarrow D^n,[(x,t)]\mapsto(1-t)x$. You can easily verify, that it is well defined (as $[(x,1)]$ is mapped to $0$ for every $x\in S^{n-1}$), that its image is $D^n$ (as $(1-t)x$ has an euclidean norm of $1-t$ (using $\|x\|_2=1$ as $x\in S^{n-1}$) with $0\leq 1-t\leq 1$) and that it is continuous (as the composition $S^{n-1}\times I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n,(x,t)\mapsto(1-t)x$ with the open quotient map is). It has an inverse function:
$$g\colon
D^n\rightarrow CS^{n-1},
x\mapsto\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
[(x/\|x\|_2,1-\|x\|_2)] & x\neq 0 \\
[(*,1)] & x=0
\end{array}\right..$$
You could either try to show, that this is continuous to conclude or use the theorem (Corollary 2.1. [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/maps+from+compact+spaces+to+Hausdorff+spaces+are+closed+and+proper) on nLab), that a bijective continuous map (which $f$ is, given the existence of $g$) from a compact space (like $CS^{n-1}$) into a Hausdorff space (like $D^n$) is a homeomorphism.

For $X=D^n$, just shift the embedded cone $CD^n\hookrightarrow\mathbb R^{n+1}$ (which is convex) down a bit (so an inner point will be on the zero point) and individually scale the vectors along every direction up or down to get $D^{n+1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for writing an answer. I am sorry but I don't understand how I will get" surface of an ordinary cone without the bottom circle" in the case of  $X=S^{1}$?

Comment: You're welcome! $S^1$ is a circle and $S^1\times I$ is the outer shell of a cylinder (without the bottom and upper ball). $S^1\times\{0\}$ and $S^1\times\{1\}$ correspond to the lower and upper circle in the boundary of that outer shell. See this image here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144861 (If you know Blender, you can use it a lot for visualisation of topological constructions.) The upper circle is now smashed down onto a point, so basically the upper holle is filled. Now drag everything down and flatten the whole construction to get $D^2$.